# android Error converting result java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, json, api

I have created an API in post method which is working fine in postman i.e it is giving desired response. But while using that API in Android it is giving error:

> Error converting result java.io.FileNotFoundException and  Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

I would appreciate anyone guiding me on how to do this.

Here is the code of `makeHttpRequest` method of `jsonparser`:

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest2(String url2 , String method,
                   String name, String password) throws IOException {

  // Making HTTP request
  try {

    // check for request method
    if (method == "POST") {
      // request method is POST

      url = new URL(url2);
      conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setUseCaches(false);
      conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
      conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
      conn.connect();

      JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
      jsonParam.put("name", name);
      //jsonParam.put("email", email);
      jsonParam.put("password", password);
      Log.d("json",String.valueOf(jsonParam));
      OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(
      conn.getOutputStream());
      out.write(jsonParam.toString());
      out.close();

    }
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
    Log.e("JSON", json);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }
  // try parse the string to a JSON object

  try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
  }
  Log.d("json3",String.valueOf(json));
  // return JSON String
  return jObj;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
conn.setDoInput(true); //After or before of setDoOutput(true) for organization :)
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

**EDIT :**
And this if you need to upload a JSON for the server:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(JsonObjectstr.getBytes().length)); // Get the json string length
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you are not checking that the request was successful, before calling the  `conn.getInputStream();` If the request failed that stream is empty and you need to call

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
```

What line number is giving you issue? If you print out the JSON to insure that the response is valid JSON.